# Using facebook's feed-dialog in WebView

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, webview, xamarin.forms

I want to share post on facebook using a `WebView` in my `Xamarin.Forms` app. The [method I found](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.4#redirect) needs a `redirect_uri`.

How do I:

- redirect to the shared post
- OR redirect to the timeline so the user can see that the post has been
  shared
- OR get facebook to show "successfully shared"

**Note:** I cannot use `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=` because its picking up photos irrelevant to the page being shared.

Comment: You could probable use facebook.com/me but there's no guaranty this would keep working.

Comment: thanks, I can work with that. They might even change the sharing URIs in the future, so its ok even if its not permanent. Please post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You could probable use `facebook.com/me` but there's no guaranty this would keep working